# JPA Disconnect to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

Exception:

> The last packet successfully received from the server was 2,405,585
>   milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was
>   30,340 milliseconds ago.
>           javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract
>   ResultSet
>           WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
>           ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Already closed.
>             at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
>             at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
>             at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>             at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:310)
>             at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.getResultList(Unknown Source)
>             at **com.health.dao.HospitalDaoImpl.findByPostcode(HospitalDaoImpl.java:32)**
>             at com.health.service.HospitalServiceImpl.findHospitalByPostCode(HospitalServiceImpl.java:21)
>             at com.health.travel.HospitalController.search(HospitalController.java:64)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>             at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
>             at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
>             at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
>             at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
>             at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
>             at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>             at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
>             at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
>             at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>             at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
>             at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>             at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>             at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>             at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>             at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>             at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>             at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
>             at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
>             at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
>             at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>             at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>             at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>           Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
>             at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
>             at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>             at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
>             at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
>             at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
>             at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
>             at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
>             at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
>             at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
>             at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
>             at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
>             at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
>             at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
>             at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
>             at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
>             at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
>             at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
>             at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
>             at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
>             at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
>             at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
>             ... 46 more
>           Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure

com.health.dao.HospitalDaoImpl.findHospitalByPostCode

```
/**
     * Find hospital by post code
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public List<Hospital> findByPostcode(int postcode) {
        try {
            String str = "SELECT h FROM Hospital h WHERE h.postcode BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2";
            Query query = em.createQuery(str);
            query.setParameter(1, postcode - 2);
            query.setParameter(2, postcode + 2);
            return query.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            em.close();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `em.close()` twice in your method, but you shouldn't need any of them. As you have the method annotated with `@Transactional`, the Spring framework will take care of managing it as a declarative transaction and opening-closing the connection (if you have it properly configured).

**See also:**

- [Spring Transaction Management](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)